# updated Xcode to 9.1 but it keeps saying 9.0.1

Tags: xcode, xcode9.1

I have updated my iPhone to 11.1.1 and Xcode to 9.1, but Xcode keeps saying that I am using 9.0.1 which is against what I have done and what the App Store says ( updated done to 9.1 ).

Any idea on how to fix that ?

I cannot compile my project to my device.

I have restarted Xcode, My Mac.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: No.. still the same issue, I am currently using the simulator.  any thought ?